# Dropzone is sending $_FILES empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropzone

i have a dropzone and i'm trying to send the files uploaded to a php file, but i'm not receiving anything. Here's my html and js code.

HTML

```
<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
        <input style="display:none" name="file_c" id="file_c" type="file" multiple>

    <div id="preview">
    </div>
    <div id="dropzonePreviewTemplate" style="display: none">
      <div id="template-preview" class="dz-preview dz-nofile-preview">

        <div class="small">
          <span class="" data-dz-name></span> <span class="pull-right">(<span class="dz-size" data-dz-size></span>)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <button id="sendForm"></button>
    </div>
```

and my JS

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(function() {
    //Dropzone class
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
        url: "url.php",
        paramName: "file_c",
        maxFilesize: 50,
        maxFiles: 10,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        dictDefaultMessage:"<?php echo _e('Click here or drag and drop to upload your files'); ?>",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        init: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.options.dictRemoveFile = "<span style='margin-left:5px; color:red; position:right;' title='Remove'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></span>";


        }


    });
});

$('#sendForm').click(function() {
    var enviar = Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone");
    enviar.processQueue();
});
```

On my php i used the error_log function to see what i was getting and i got this:

```
{"file_c":{"name":"","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":4,"size":0}}
```

And when i check the params send on POST on my console, the input file_c is empty.
Does anyone know what am i doing wrong? I can't seem to find an error

Comment: Try to change paramName : "file_c[]", since you are sending multiple files and you are getting error 4.

Comment: You mean change file_c to file_c[]?

Comment: Yes, try to put that

Comment: I just did, changed the paramName:"file_c[]", but i'm getting the same error :/